# Connect Raspberry PI 3 B to Bluetooth speaker and microphone

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have Bluetooth speaker which has microphone in it, when I use it with iPhone and my PC, the microphone works fine.
Now I connected it to Raspbian on Raspberry  PI 3 B via inbuilt bluetooth, speaker is working but OS is not recognizing microphone. I tried googling for this issue, but no option worked, I am getting only one option in alsamixer. I tried installing bluetooth audio packages also.

Comment: I am very interested, thanks for asking.
I would like to buy a similar product for my Raspberry Pi (there are many out there speaker / bluetooth mic combo):
https://www.amazon.de/Anker-SoundCore-Bluetooth-Lautsprecher-Wireless/dp/B01E6ZLLPW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1474974253&sr=8-1&keywords=anker+soundcore+nano

I just do not know if anybody was able to use both speaker and mic on the Pi.
I would also love to have one not using batteries, what kind of model did you get?

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but a poor question cannot be turned into a good one by a bounty. " I tried googling for this issue, but no option worked" tells me nothing about what you have actually tried. My best guess is that you picked A2DP profile which doesn't expose the microphone, but that's one guess among many others.

Comment: Any success with this issue? I'm struggling to have the headset profile working as well...

Comment: I made a step by step guide for alsa + bluez: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90267/how-to-stream-sound-to-a-bluetooth-device-from-a-raspberry-pi-zero

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here: http://youness.net/raspberry-pi/bluetooth-headset-raspberry-pi-3-ad2p-hsp

Basically, Raspberry Pi uses Broadcom BCM43438 “combo” shipset for Wi-Fi and Bluetooth, and there is some problem with the chipset/driver/firmware. The solution entails installing additional drivers for bluetooth support, using an **external usb dongle** for bluetooth connectivity, disabling the onboard bluetooth transmitter, and installing the correct drivers for the dongle.

I'd recommend viewing the solution from the link directly instead of having me copy-paste it for you, since it will be kept up to date with the authors research and solutions, and because it is a **very** long post.

Hope this helps!